# How to match a hex sequence of characters and replace it with white space in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text that i need to clean some characters. This characters are showed in the pictures i attached to the question. I want to replace them with white space `x20`.

[image: First hex sequence]

[image: Second hex sequence]

My attempt was to use `preg_replace`.

```
$result = preg_replace("/[\xef\x82\xac\x09|\xef\x81\xa1\x09]/", "\x20", $string);
```

For a particular case this approach works, but for some cases it won't, because for example i had a text with a comma and it matched `x82` and removed it from that text.

How could i write my regex to search exact this sequence `ef 82 ac 09`, or the other one `ef 81 a1 09`, and not for each pair separately like `ef` `82` `ac` `09`?

Comment: @anubhava you have the string in the picture.

Comment: Have you tried using something simple like `str_replace` instead?

Comment: @Half Crazed `str_replace` that's the first thing i tried.

Comment: Interesting. I tried both. Can you post the file with the characters? It could be an encoding issue?

Comment: @Half Crazed have you read my question ? I asked how to write my `REGEX` expression to match exactly this group `ef82ac09`, because now my current solution matches each pair independently as `ef`, `82`,`ac`,09.

Comment: @anubhava do you see this `ef82ac09`? I need a `REGEX` expression to capture it, and replace it by `20`, what part of the question is not clear for you ?

Comment: I think you match any of the 6 different hex bytes or pipe character in the character class. Probably wanted to use a group. Also the byte sequence of your regex is different from the sample picture. Try with a group: `(?:\xef\x81\xac\x09|\xef\x82\xa1\x09)`

Comment: @Jonny 5 that's exactly what i am trying to do, to group them, and it does not match. I took your example and no match again.

Comment: As I suggested, a sample text of input is needed using `var_dump` not a picture.

Comment: So if you match 4 bytes, you're wanting to also replace all 4 with a \x20?

Comment: I ask because if so, regex does not support a reference to the count of the match... so if you wanted to match a group of `n` characters, there's no direct reference available for `r` repetitions in the replacement. You would need to write a loop..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Rd6a83VE here is a piece of text, @Half Crazed yes all of them.

Comment: `$result = preg_replace("/(?:\xef\x81\xac\x09|\xef\x82\xa1\x09)/", "\x20", $string);` [doesn't work for you?](https://eval.in/404243)

Comment: @Jonny 5 yes the same i did,  as soon i group them nothing gets replaced.

Comment: Try `$result = preg_replace("/(?:\xef\x81\xac|\xef\x82\xa1)/", "\x20", $string);` [sample @ eval.in](https://eval.in/404252)

Comment: @Jonny 5 did not think to try it without `09` :D it worked! I thought this `09` is part of that sequence.

Comment: Great you got it going! :] just used [the ones, that bin2hex showed](https://eval.in/404252).

Comment: I used a hex editor and it showed `09` as you can see in the picture. Thanks everybody for help!

Comment: The data seems to be valid UTF-8. The 4 byte sequences you want to remove is actually 2 characters, the first character encoded in 3 bytes belongs private use area of Unicode, the other character is 09, a tab character.

Comment: @Constantin: Is the issue fixed? If yes, ask Jonny to post the answer and accept it.

Comment: @Jonny5 please post your solution as an answer so we could close this question as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) You match any of the 6 different hex bytes or pipe character in the character class. Probably wanted to use a group `(?:`...`|`...`)` for matching the different byte sequences.

2.) Also the byte sequences do not match the image. Seems like you messed up two bytes. The picture shows: `ef 82 a1 09` and `ef 81 ac 09` vs your try: `\xef\x82\xac\x09` | `\xef\x81\xa1\x09`

3.) When [testing your input sample](https://eval.in/414724)

```
$str = "de la nouvelle;      Fourniture $         Option :";

foreach(preg_split("//u", $str) AS $v) {
  var_dump($v, bin2hex($v)); echo "\n";
}
```

it turned out, that `09` was too much. The characters to be removed are actually `ef81ac` and `ef82a1`.
So the right regex would be `(?:\xef\x81\xac|\xef\x82\xa1)`

```
$result = preg_replace("/(?:\xef\x81\xac|\xef\x82\xa1)/", "\x20", $string);
```

See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/414723)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the whole file is UTF-8 encoded text, then you might want to remove the characters from [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), since `\xef\x82\xac` decodes to code point U+F0AC and `\xef\x81\xa1` decodes to code point U+F061, which belong to the Private Use Area U+E000..U+F8FF.

```
$result = preg_replace("~\p{Co}~u", " ", $input);
```

`\p{Co}` is the character class of all characters belong to Other, Private Use category in Unicode, which includes all characters in the 3 ranges U+E000..U+F8FF, U+F0000..U+FFFFD, U+100000..U+10FFFD.